# How to make a subquery with ORDER BY mysql

Tags: sql

Hello i have this query that works, the query shows tasks that admin posts and they are ordered by the date and status of that post (Active, Inactive, Pending.. etc) now the admin also has an emergency status that is (Urgent, Low, Middle, Normal) to show the importance of that task. This is the working query:

```
SELECT t.`id_ticket`,ts.`status_desc`, t.`data`, t.`client_name`, t.`email`, t.`number`, nu.`emergency_desc`, tp.`problem_desc`, t.`details`, t.`staff`,t.updated,u.name as selected,t.status_id,t.emergency_id,t.creator_staff
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN  user u on u.id=t.dtg
LEFT JOIN problem_type tp ON t.problem_type = tp.problem_id
LEFT JOIN urgent_level nu on t.urgent_id =nu.urgent_id
LEFT JOIN ticket_status ts on t.status_id=ts.status_id
Where vis=1 ORDER BY t.status_id asc,t.data desc LIMIT 100
```

It shows first the tasks ordered by the latest date and then those tasks are ordered by the status, now i want to add also this:

```
ORDER BY urgent_id asc
```

but when i add it on the existing `ORDER BY` it shows tasks from older dates like **2021** with priority the `urgent_id`

Comment: And the problem even occurs when `urgent_id` ordering happens last (after status_id and data?

Comment: i put it in this order  `ORDER BY urgent_id asc, t.status_id asc,t.data desc LIMIT 100` and shows me data with URGENT status from 2021 then is 2022 etc, i want to keep it as it is latest tasks with the status as it is but those to ordered by the urgent_Id

Comment: You have to do it like this: `ORDER BY t.status_id asc, t.data desc, urgent_id asc` if you want it to have the least effect on the query. Also, if these are Strings, sorting won't be much effective given that these are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Laisender it didnt work its like it was before basically nothing changed.

Comment: @Laisender if i remove the t.status_id asc the query  makes changes shows the todays task by the urgent_id but not from the status

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that you are not storing dates as dates.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid dates  are stored as timestamp

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i changed it as dates but still nothing

Comment: Do you need the exact 100 results listed in the initial query and after that, reorder by urgent_id asc?

Comment: @Benilson the 100 result show good in order from the latest date and then order by the status but now im trying to add also to reorder them by the urgent_status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `t.urgent_id` in your field list and use a subquery to keep the result and reorder by this value in the subquery.

```
SELECT list.* from (
    SELECT t.`id_ticket`, ts.`status_desc`, t.`data`, t.`client_name`, 
           t.`email`, t.`number`, nu.`emergency_desc`, tp.`problem_desc`,
           t.`details`, t.`staff`,t.updated,u.name as selected,
           t.status_id,t.emergency_id,t.creator_staff,
           t.urgent_id
    FROM ticket t
    LEFT JOIN  user u on u.id=t.dtg
    LEFT JOIN problem_type tp ON t.problem_type = tp.problem_id
    LEFT JOIN urgent_level nu on t.urgent_id =nu.urgent_id
    LEFT JOIN ticket_status ts on t.status_id=ts.status_id
    Where vis=1 
    ORDER BY t.status_id asc, t.data desc LIMIT 100
) as list
ORDER BY list.urgent_id asc, list.status_id asc, t.data desc
```